# Spring cloud config server not working with spring 2.7.8 & spring cloud (2021.0.5)

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Recently, I have implemented spring cloud config server using spring cloud & its not working.

I am using:

```
SpringBoot: 2.7.8
Cloud: 2021.0.5
Java: 1.8
```

Dependencies:

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

Application properties:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri= https://bitbucket.org/org-name/repo-name.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=my_username
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=my_password
spring.cloud.config.server.git.force-pull=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master
spring.cloud.config.server.git.try-master-branch=true
spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true
spring.profiles.active=native
```

Result:
http://localhost:8080/payments/dev

```
{"name":"payments","profiles":["dev"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

Comment: The property [`spring.profiles.active=native`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#_file_system_backend) activates the profile in Spring Cloud Config Server that does not use Git but loads configuration files from the local classpath or file system.